# Printing a perl script within another perl script?

Tags: perl, printing, nested

Hi I am new to stackoverflow.  I've tried looking a way to print another perl script within a different perl script and the only advice I came across is escaping the variables using a backslash...but I tried this and it does not work.

My goal is to write a perl script to make a bunch of new perl scripts but as it is it won't allow me to use variable/arrays/etc in a print "".  Is there a way around this? Thanks in advance!

Here is my preliminary script:

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl
    use warnings;
    use strict;

    my $idfile = $ARGV[0];
    open (IDFILE,'<',$idfile)
    or die "Could not open $idfile \n";

    my $outfile_name;
    my $outfile = $outfile_name."pl";
    open (OUTFILE, '>', $outfile)
    or die "Could not open $outfile \n";

    while (my $line = <IDFILE>) {
        chomp ($line);
        if ($line =~ /(T4-GC_[0-9]+)/) {
            my $outfile_name = "Pull_".$line;
            my $script = "
    #!/usr/bin/perl
    use warnings;
    use strict;
    use Bio::SearchIO;
    use Bio::SeqIO;

    my @ARGV = glob("*.fa");

    foreach my $fil (@ARGV) {
        my $seqio  = Bio::SeqIO->new(-format => 'fasta', -file  => $fil);
            while (my $seqobj = $seqio->next_seq) {
            my $seqid = $seqobj->display_id;
            $fil =~ /([A-Z]+[0-9]+)/;
            my $phage_name = $1;
            my $id = $seqid."|".$phage_name;
            my $nuc = $seqobj->seq();
            if ($seqid =~ /**$line**/) {
                    print ">$id\n$nuc\n";
            }
    }
    }"
        print OUTFILE $script;
        }
    }
```

And this is the error I get back:

```
    String found where operator expected at make_perl_pull_genes_files.pl line 33, near                 "my $id = $seqid.""
      (Might be a runaway multi-line "" string starting on line 25)
        (Missing semicolon on previous line?)
    Backslash found where operator expected at make_perl_pull_genes_files.pl line 36, near "$id\"
      (Might be a runaway multi-line "" string starting on line 33)
        (Missing operator before \?)
    Backslash found where operator expected at make_perl_pull_genes_files.pl line 36, near "$nuc\"
        (Missing operator before \?)
    String found where operator expected at make_perl_pull_genes_files.pl line 39, near "}""
      (Might be a runaway multi-line "" string starting on line 36)
        (Missing semicolon on previous line?)
    syntax error at make_perl_pull_genes_files.pl line 25, near "*."
      (Might be a runaway multi-line "" string starting on line 18)
    Global symbol "$id" requires explicit package name at make_perl_pull_genes_files.pl line 36.
    Global symbol "$nuc" requires explicit package name at make_perl_pull_genes_files.pl line 36.
    Execution of make_perl_pull_genes_files.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Comment: Why you need to create new pl files? It could be better to create one pl an call it with different command line, if you need.

Answer (score 5):

Use a HERE document with single quotes around the leading delimiter.

```
print <<'EOT';
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Bio::SearchIO;
use Bio::SeqIO;

my @ARGV = glob("*.fa");

foreach my $fil (@ARGV) {
  my $seqio  = Bio::SeqIO->new(-format => 'fasta', -file  => $fil);
  while (my $seqobj = $seqio->next_seq) {
    my $seqid = $seqobj->display_id;
    $fil =~ /([A-Z]+[0-9]+)/;
    my $phage_name = $1;
    my $id = $seqid."|".$phage_name;
    my $nuc = $seqobj->seq();
    if ($seqid =~ /**$line**/) {
      print ">$id\n$nuc\n";
    }
  }
}
EOT
```

Note that the trailing delimiter must be cuddled by newlines: \nTRAILING\n in your source.  Don't attempt to indent it, for instance.  Another place you can stuff text like this, within your source file, is beyond a `__DATA__` line.  You would then read it back through `<DATA>`.